# How to apply jwt django rest token to access other Apis

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, access-token

I am generating jwt token with this url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/

HTTP 200 OK
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "refresh": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTUyOTQyOTUwMSwianRpIjoiZmYxOTFmN2JhN2NhNDY2MWI0OTUzZGU2NmVlNjg3ODEiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoyfQ.SssEuSxKj09vshLq74h5NPMZFg8V-0oee9ZqLHzINV4",
    "access": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTI5MzQzNDAxLCJqdGkiOiJlNDNlZTE2MTlmOTM0ZjQxOWM4NWRiZGYxMzZkMzk2ZiIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjJ9.l9CPDVg371uIvXAVlLdV_uhzYYn9ejzEpCZLFKo1fU4"
}
```

And i have an API (http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/userdetails/) which lists the user
code is like below

```
class UserDetailsAPIView(APIView):

    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer
    def get(self, request, format=None):   

        @permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
        usernames = [user.username for user in User.objects.all()]
        return Response(usernames)
```

When i access API (http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/userdetails/) it is displying error
"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." 
So how will i access API (http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/userdetails/) by providing generated jwt token?

Comment: You can pass your authentication in header. You can lookup usage here:
 https://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#usage